# why my state situation does not change when choose date in select opt

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, state, use-state

```
//=> my state
const [date, setDate] = useState({ year: "", month: "", full: "" });
```

```
///=> here is to change state situation after month changed
else if (target.name === "cardMonth") {
    target.value = formatMonthDate(target.value);
    setDate({ ...date, month: target.value });
   
  } 

//=> here is my select option area to select date 

<div className="form-group">
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <select
              className="custom-select"
              name="cardMonth"
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
              onFocus={(e) => handleInputFocus(e)}
            >
              {months.map((month) => (
                <option value={month} key={month}>
                  {month}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

the problem is when i chose a month for the first time , then it can't appear in state but when i chose a new date then my state takes first state. shortly state situation follow changes one step back. for example : ı chose january first time nd it is not appeaar in my state . later ı choose february and ı see january in state not february . if i choose a new one then i ll see january and february only not new one. it goes like this and i almost spent one day for this.

Comment: where do you get `months ` from ?

Comment: import { installement, initialValues, months, years } from "./installement"; ı take it from another js file. it is json

Comment: can we see handleInputChange

Comment: sure . https://github.com/otontas11/creditCard

Comment: normally ı m trying to credit card nd ı wanna use my own date instant of the credit card date . but as ı said above , i have state problem so ı cant finish this task

Comment: @Oktay tontaş, looks like your github repo isnt updated with the latest version of your code.